# Setting up versioning repositories - one big or many small?

Tags: mercurial, project, tortoisehg

I have worked with mercurial for some time now and it feels like a big asset to what I do. It's great to never mess up code again by accident.

I love the workflow and wants to setup versioning on all my projects. **What is the best option of the two below illustrated alternatives?**

Alternative A:

```
/repo/
  /repo/ownWork/
     /project1/
  /repo/clients/
     /client1/
```

Alternative  B:

```
/repo/project1/
/repo/client1/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a "right" answer. As with many things, it depends.
Personally, I have a separate repository for each project and, possibly, one or more repositories for shared code. With distributed source control you have to check out/clone the whole repository, not just sub-folders like you can with, say, SVN. Therefore I like to keep each project/client as self contained as possible but, if necessary, clone shared repos too.

However, I still maintain a single 'central' web server to host them all. I like 'distributed' and I like 'centralised' too :-)

The good thing about hg is that it seems (to my newbie eyes, anyway) to be very easy to chop and change your layout/structure as time progresses.

Answer (score 1):

In mercurial it's very easy to combine repos later, but not possible to separate them without invalidating existing clones.  Start separate and merge later if it has become a hassle.  Consider subrepos for code shared among projects.